# new MongoId objects with php

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I am trying to create new objects on MongoDB via PHP with personalized IDs, like this:

```
    $user = Array(
        '_id'  => "$id",
        'name' => $name,
    );
```

The problem with this is that when I query for IDs, I need to use the following:

```
$query = Array( '_id' => "$id" );
```

instead of the more appropriate

```
$query = Array( '_id' => new MongoId("$id") );
```

forcing me to change all the queries. I thought that I do it by fixing the inserting, by putting '_id'  => new MongoId("$id") but, if I use that, it will simply create the default
mongodb id, insead of my personalized one.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: as stated in this page here: http://www.php.net/manual/it/mongoid.construct.php it needs to be a _24 hexidecimal characters_. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little confused by exactly what you are asking for here, however, I believe I might just understand.

If you are using a `_id` different to the default `ObjectId` that MongoDB uses for the primary key of a row then you should not use `ObjectId` or in fact `MongoId` to create that object.

You should only use `MongoId` when you using the default `_id` that is provided, if you use your own the `ObjectId` (`MongoId`) will not function as you expect.

So the answer here is to stop using the `MongoId`.

Comment: my question is then: might removing the MongoId object be a problem for the functioning of the DB? Thank you.

Comment: @johnsmith No, the MongoId is simply a PHP side wrapper for OjbectId, so if you are not using ObjectIds within your _id there is no problem